# How does Apple or Android calculate speed in devices?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation

There are any documentation for this? I've checked many formulas and algorithms but didn't find an explicit definition how they get the speed provided in Geolocation object.

Comment: In android you can check the sensors https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPS chipset provides the current velocity to the system along with the current location.

The chipset may compute the velocity by comparing location over time and correcting for the curvature of the Earth at the current location, or from the Doppler shift of the received satellite signals.

Whichever method is used, the operating system doesn’t need to do any processing to get the speed. The velocity data is provided along with location and altitude data directly from the GPS chip (actually chips in many newer devices support both GPS and GLONASS, but which system is used is not visible to the user).

Physics.org has a [simple explanation of how GPS works](http://www.physics.org/article-questions.asp?id=55)

> Wherever you are on the planet, at least four GPS satellites are ‘visible’ at any time. Each one transmits information about its position and the current time at regular intervals. These signals, travelling at the speed of light, are intercepted by your GPS receiver, which calculates how far away each satellite is based on how long it took for the messages to arrive.
>
> Once it has information on how far away at least three satellites are, your GPS receiver can pinpoint your location using a process called trilateration.

But you can search for more detailed explanations of the mathematics and physics involved.

Comment: But there are any documentation how they get this data and process to get speed?

Comment: I wouldn’t think so, not from an iOS or Android point of view, because the operating system doesn’t do this. You could read about how the GPS system works; basically it receives time signals from at least 4 satellites. Since it is known where each of the satellites are at any point in time, the difference in the time received from each satellite can be used to compute the distance to each satellite. The gps chip then solves an equation to determine the point on the Earth that would give that set of time differences from that set of satellites

Comment: The other approach that some chips use is to analyse the Doppler shift in the GPS radio signal. Since the velocity of the satellites is known, any variation between the actual Doppler shift and the expected Doppler shift is due to the velocity of the receiver.

Comment: So do you think this speed variable provided in Android and iOS it's just gathered from GPS's chipset?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing that the operating system can do in cpu that the location chip can’t do more efficiently in hardware. On newer iOS devices with a motion processor even  functions such as step counting and determining the current motion type (walking, running, driving) is done in hardware.

Comment: I see. So the answer for my question is: There's no way to know how speed is calculated in iOS/Android devices because it depends of their chipsets?

Comment: Yes. I checked on the chipset used in the iPhone 7, and the manufacturer (Broadcom) doesn’t seem to make that information publicly available

Answer (score 0):

It basically scans your location (i.e. your latitude and longitude) and compares with the last check. Using euclidian distance, it can get the distance in the period of time. With the time (for example, if it scans your location every 2 seconds), it can easily estimate your speed by doing Speed = Distance/2.

Comment: I know, maybe i wasn't clear that i am looking for a proper documentation for that. about euclidian distance are you sure about this?